# Deleting a Google Workspaces Account -

Tags: google

Friends, I'm trying to delete an account I have on Google Workspaces but when I click on "delete your account", I get a warning that I have active projects in GCP.
I don't have any project in GCP, but when I open GCP I see that there is one called "system-gsuite" and under it "apps-script" and I can't delete it...
Can someone help me solve this problem?[Account Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIsKk.png)
[GCP Manage Resources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w82iU.png)

Comment: What happened when you tried to delete the project?

Answer (score 0):

[As you want to delete your workspace account there are some steps to follow:](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1257646?hl=en)

**Step 1: Save your data (such as emails, documents)**

*After you cancel your Google Workspace subscription, your users' Google Workspace data will be deleted and can’t be restored.*

Before you cancel your Google Workspace subscription, download any user data you want to save. This includes Gmail messages, Google Calendar events, Google Chat messages, and files stored in Google Drive.

The easiest way to download and export your users' data is to use the Data Export tool.

*Note that cancelling Google Workspace doesn’t remove user accounts, groups, or your organizational structure. These items remain unless you delete your organization’s Google Account.*

**Step 2: Cancel your Google Workspace subscription.**

Here’s how to cancel Google Workspace and stop being billed for your subscription. Do this after exporting any user data you want to save.

1. Sign in to your Google Admin console.

Sign in using an account with super administrator privileges

2. On the Admin console Home page, go to Billing and then Manage subscriptions.
3. Click your subscription and then Cancel Subscription.

Read about charges after you cancel.

4. Select a reason for canceling and then click Continue.
5. Check the box to confirm you read the information and want to
   continue.
6. Enter your email address and then click Cancel My Subscription.,

**(Optional) Step 3: Delete your organization’s Google Account**
If you no longer want a Google Account for your organization, delete the entire account. Deleting your organization’s account frees your domain within 24 hours for use with a new Google Account.

For steps, [go to Delete your organization’s Google Account.](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9468554)

Step 1: Save Billing records

Step 2: Save user data

Step 3: Delete Marketplace apps

Step 4: Save and delete GCP data

Step 5: Cancel all your subscriptions

Step 6: Delete your account